# Android Studio doesn't recognise anymore an app

Tags: android

I've just build an android app using Android Studio on Windws xt.

It worked fine, so I closed it, but I reopened it just after few second because I wanted to add a button.

Well my app isn't reconised AS says that I should add a module! Besides every xml files are shown with a lot of red lines (mistakes)!

Please help me to understand what happened.

Thank you very much,
Nino V

Comment: "it does not show any research": that's not my case, before asking helps I ALWAYS try to do research or to study again all documentation I can get. "it is unclear"? Well isn't it possible to ask for further information? "it is not useful": isn't that a personal extimation? Thanks to that 'anonymous' user.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening settings.gradle file and add:

include 'nameofyourmodule'

Comment: @Markerhack: thank you for your kindness. I've built about ten apps as exercises and I don't have any settings.gradle!

Comment: Are you sure? You should have one settings.gradle in the root of your project (not the module, the project) which should have the includes with the modules the project contains. Are you running latest version of Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED I've started a new project and copied the old src and res to the new project (which does not have any setting.gradle).